# ¿Cómo solucionar el Failure parsing JSON error en fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando realizar un calendario de eventos con fullcalendar y php. Tengo unos datos guardados en una BD los cuales quiero mostrar en el calendario, pero por más que intento no logro que se muestren la consola del navegador. Lo único que me marca es esta advertencia:

> Failure parsing JSON {message: 'Failure parsing JSON', xhr: XMLHttpRequest}

El código php que utilizo es

```
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos");
 $query->execute();
 $resultado = $query->get_result();

 $eventos = [];

while($row_events = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $title = $row_events['title'];
    $color = $row_events['color'];
    $eventos[] = [
        'title' => $title, 
        'color' => $color, 
        ];
}
echo json_encode($eventos);
```

codigo js para mostrar eventos

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                //creando vistas semana dia
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today,boton',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,list',
                    center: 'title',
                },
                events: {
                    url: 'logica/eventos.php',
                    
                }
            });
            //cambiar idioma a espanol
            calendar.setOption('locale', 'Es');
            calendar.render();
        });
```

He buscado por todas partes y realmente no sé cuál es mi error.
Un último dato: eventos.php me devuelve lo siguiente

```
[{"title":"titulo","color":"#FF5722"},{"title":"azsdasdas","color":"#8BC34A"}]
```

Version full calendar: 5
Version php: 8

Update:
Eh probado con alguna de las sugerencias hechas y aun sigo sin poder resolver esto. Por si sirve de algo adjunto lo que me marca pestaña de network. No entiendo bien pero creo que si esta recibiendo los datos o si alguien puede orientarme. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que version de Fullcalendar estas utilizando

Comment: Hola gracias por responder version 5

Answer (score 0):

Hacen falta datos :

- Versión Fullcalendar
- Versión php

Para ver realmente lo que esta sucediendo  en las `herramientas de desarrollo del navegador`  tienes   la pestaña `network` y ahí tendras la subpestaña `Fetch/HRX` en ella encontraras el estado de la solicitud a `logica/eventos.php`

No tienes errores en el código pero :
Hay varios campos que hacen falta

```php
  $eventos[] = [
        'id'=> 1,
        'title'=> "Envento de prueba",
        'start'=> date("Y-m-d) . "T" . "13:00" ,
        'end' => date("Y-m-d) . "T" . "13:30",
        'color' => "#FAFAFA#,
    ];
```

En cuanto a la respuesta : agrega en los `headers` el código de respuesta  y el tipo de respuesta

```php
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  http_response_code(200);
  echo json_encode($datosPaciente);
  exit;
```

**Concejos que no has pedido :**

Recuerda que fullcalendar envía un rango de fechas como parámetros por la `url` puedes utilizar estos datos para hacer tu consulta  a la  base de datos mas rapido

Obtenemos el rango de fechas

```php
$start = explode("T",$_GET['start'])[0];
$end   = explode("T",$_GET['end'])[0];
```

Mejoramos el `select`

```php
//Asumo que la fecha de inicio  y fin de cada cita la guardas en dos campos separados
     $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos where fechaInicio >= '$start' and fechaFin <= '$end'");
```

Comment: gracias intentare poner en practica los consejos por cierto la version de php que uso es la 8 y full calendar v5

Comment: @FerDaniela No olvides marcar la respuesta